# non-analytic smooth function

Tags: analysis

Given the function $$f(z) = \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} \exp\left(-\sqrt{|k|}\right) z^{k}$$
Defined on the unit circle $S^1$.

That $f$ is smooth is not hard to see.

Why is there not a $\Phi$ on an open neighborhood $V$ of $S^1$ such that $\Phi$ is holomorphic and $\Phi$ restricted to $S^1$ is equal to $f$?

Comment: Because the series only converges for $\lvert z\rvert = 1$. For every $r > 1$, we have $\lim\limits_{k\to+\infty} \exp(-\sqrt{\lvert k\rvert})\cdot r^k \to +\infty$, similar for $r < 1$, then take the limit as $k \to -\infty$.